# how to arrange an image, an h1 tag and a span in an <li> tag?

Tags: html, css

I am using 960 grids. The image is supposed to be located in the left side and the texts should appear on the right side of the image. The text on top is in an h1 tag and the text below it is a smaller one.

And the texts should be horizontally aligned with the image. But, cannot figure out how to make that happen.

Any help is appreciated.

```css
li {
 list-style:none;}

.about .grid_10 ul >li img{
 float: left;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
width: 50px;
 height:50px;}

.about .grid_10 ul >li h1{
 float: left;
 font-size: 36px;
 font-family: 'OpenSans';
 font-weight: 800;
 line-height: 1.1em;
 margin-left: 20px;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);}
 
.about .grid_10 ul >li h1 span{
 float: left;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-family: 'OpenSans';
 margin-top:0;}
```

```html
 <div class="grid_10">
 <ul>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="My_Logo"/>
    </li>
    <li> 
        <h1>aaaaa aaaaaaa
            <br>
            <span>
                aaaaa aaaaaa  aaaaaaa aaaaaaaa
            </span>
        </h1>
    </li>                    
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: do you have to keep your html like you order it?

Comment: No, not necessarily

Answer (score 0):

I changed your html layout and added the right css

```css
   
.grid_10  img {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

.grid_10  .text-container{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 150px;
    line-height: 150px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid_10">
    <h1>aaaaa aaaaaaa</h1>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="My_Logo"/>
    <span class="text-container">
        aaaaa aaaaaa  aaaaaaa aaaaaaaa
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but, actually, h1 tag is supposed to be located on top of the span and on the right side of the image, in a way that the text in the span is an explanation of the text in h1. And they are supposed to stick together

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: flex; flex-direction:row;` properties to `ul` tag. This makes elements inside `ul` to be shown in one line. You can adjust horizontal alignment with `align-items` property on `ul` tag.

Also I'd move `<span>` tag outside the `<h1>` tag for better styling.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a `float: left;` to your `<li>` item in the CSS to make the text appear to the right of the image.